# ASP.NET convert part of JSON file to JArray

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, json.net

I have this JSON that I'm trying to parse with Newtonsoft and convert to an array:

```
{
"generatedAt": "2022-01-01 02:03:25",
"myitems": [
{
    "id": "1795089",
    "location": {
        "name": "Myplace",
        "countryCode": "DE"
    },
}
,
{
    "id": "1795070",
    "location": {
        "name": "Roseplace",
        "countryCode": "US"
    },
}

],
"count": 2
}
```

What I tried:

```
Dim jsonArray As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray
jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json)
```

But this does not find the `myitems` array.

So then I tried:

```
Dim obj As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
Dim result As JObject = DirectCast(obj("myitems"), JObject)
```

But I don't know if this is the recommended approach or how to convert that object to a `JArray`.

Comment: If it starts with `{` rather than `[`, it's gonna be a single object, not an array. However, that single object might include an array property named MyItems

Comment: This should suffice once you've parsed the Object: `Dim result As JArray = obj("myItems")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jarray.parse requires an array source...However

```
Dim jstring as string = "{""generatedAt"": ""2022-01-01 02:03:25"",""myitems"": [{""id"": ""1795089"",""location"":{""name"":""Myplace"",""countryCode"":""DE""},},{""id"":""1795070"",""location"": {""name"": ""Roseplace"",""countryCode"": ""US""},}],""count"": 2}"
Dim jo = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jstring)
Dim ja = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(jo("myitems").toString)
```

But once you parse the object, do you need to parse the array?

Comment: Isn't `jo("myitems")` already a JArray?

Comment: Nevermind. I see it's a JToken, which is a parent for JObject and JArray. Maybe a cast, though, instead of re-parsing?

Comment: Well, I had to check, and it **IS** already a JArray: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OGbWD0

Comment: Yes, this whole exercise is really moot once you've parsed the complete object.

Comment: Thanks. I did it like this now: `Dim jsonArray As JArray = DirectCast(obj("myitems"), JArray)`

Comment: Great.  JUST FYI: Direct cast is not needed.  Take a peek at `obj("myitems").GetType()`